# Spring boot test class not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, testing, spring-boot

I have some problem working with Spring test in STS when using Spring-boot:
I wrote an empty Test Class:

```
package com.movieGo.repo;
@Transactional
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MovieGoApplication.class)
public class CinemaRepoTests {

}
```

And I got a `classNotFound` error like this:

```
Class not found com.movieGo.repo.CinemaRepoTests
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.movieGo.repo.CinemaRepoTests
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)   
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClasses(RemoteTestRunner.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Have I missed something? How can I fix that? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I've seen this problem when the project has build path/compilation problems that prevent Eclipse from compiling the class file. Check you workspace for errors.

Comment: Are you using maven? Could you post you pom.xml? If not, check you class path settings in STS